# Spotfire Web Player not opening data tables

Tags: spotfire

How can I get data tables to display in a Spotfire Web Player? I have several analyses that I'd like to be able to open in the Spotfire Web Player but the data connections are to Data Tables, not linked Excel files with relative server path names.

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to use a data connection or an information link to retrieve your data rather than the data provider access. If you are using a data provider access, I see 3 options:

1. Embed the data
2. Use information links
3. Use automation services to automatically refresh data